# Installing fuerte and indigo together?

Tags: ros-fuerte, android, ros-indigo, android-core

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have Indigo installed, but I can not seem to get rosjava/android_core working, and the documentation for rosjava on indigo is minimal. I was thinking of moving to fuerte. I have two options, either to uninstall indigo and install fuerte, or install them side by side. I don't know which is the better/easier option

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196368/installing-fuerte-and-indigo-together?/) by [mango](https://answers.ros.org/users/20627/mango/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2015-01-07**:
It could be possible to compile the packages from source on Indigo. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not possible to have them side-by-side because fuerte only supports Ubuntu versions up to 12.04 while the "oldest" Ubuntu version indigo supports is 13.10

See:

http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu
http://wiki.ros.org/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you've got a powerful machine, you can install one version to your system and the other into a virtual machine with another Ubuntu version. If you set up networking correctly, these two can communicate together (as long as the messages used have not changed).

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2015-01-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2